# How to implement Google Adwords Conversion track code with Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress, google-ads-api

How to integrate Adwords conversion code (Event snippet) in Wordpress Contact Form 7 plugin to track conversion?

Please suggest me a solution adwords experts…

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement Google Adwords conversion code in Contact Form 7 Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47279181/how-to-implement-google-adwords-conversion-code-in-contact-form-7-wordpress)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [DOM Events](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/) created by WPCF7 to hook in and fire the conversion hit :

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
   // The mail is now sent
   gtag_report_conversion();
}, false );
```

Google documentation from [here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6331304?co=ADWORDS.IsAWNCustomer%3Dtrue&oco=0)